# C++ macro and template with multiple arguments error

Tags: c++

I have this simple (useless) code to demonstrate the problem:

```
template<typename _Tx, typename _Ty>
struct foo{};

#define TO_STRING(Type) #Type

int main()
{
    std::string sInt = TO_STRING(int);
    std::string sfoo1 = TO_STRING(foo<int, float>); //warning and unexpected value - "foo<int"
    std::string sfoo2 = TO_STRING((foo<int, float>)); //no warning, still unexpected value "(foo<int, float>)"
}
```

Is there a way to pass templates with multiple arguments to macros without using 
`()` ?

Comment: what do you compile it with, so it swallows silently when you pass either 1 or 2 arguments to macro?

Comment: @RomanSaveljev Visual Studio 2010

Comment: In C++11 there is a workaround, if you have only one such argument. Use a variadic macro, like this: `#define TO_STRING(...) #__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: Note that `_Tx` and `_Ty` are reserved names as the begin with an underscore, followed by an uppercase letter.

Comment: `#define TO_STRING(args...) #args` this seemed to work, but people say this is not standard way and GCC extension, so use at your own discretion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be ideal, but I think it will work on pretty much any compiler (and if you find one where it doesn't, it's easy to dumb down with no interface change):

```
#define TO_STRING1(_a_) #_a_
#define TO_STRING2(_a_, ...) #_a_ ", " TO_STRING1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TO_STRING3(_a_, ...) #_a_ ", " TO_STRING2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TO_STRING4(_a_, ...) #_a_ ", " TO_STRING3(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The only downside is you have to count the commas yourself, e.g.:

```
std::string sInt = TO_STRING1(int);
std::string sfoo = TO_STRING2(foo<int, float>);
```